# Ошибка инфлейтинга navigation view на 4.0.3(api 16)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer

При запуске активности сразу крашится с ошибкой инфлейтинга
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.yarmiit.ztrap/ru.yarmiit.ztrap.news}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

Собственно сам NavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_news"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/news_drawer" />
```

В хедере лишь одна картинка, так что не думаю что дело в нём. Замечу что проблема только на устройствах API < 21. Ломаю зубы об эти "сладости" уже 2 дня, выручайте! Полный листинг активности:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="ru.yarmiit.ztrap.news">
<include layout="@layout/content_news" />
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/header_md_320x180"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/srl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_rv"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<include layout="@layout/dowloading_indicator_news" />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_news"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/news_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Полный листинг ошибки:

```
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                at ru.yarmiit.ztrap.news.onCreate(news.java:51)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                at ru.yarmiit.ztrap.news.onCreate(news.java:51) 
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                             Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020066
                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:320)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:196)
                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
                                                                at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
                                                                at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:495)
                                                                at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:436)
                                                                at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:112)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:245)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:169)
                                                                at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                at ru.yarmiit.ztrap.news.onCreate(news.java:51) 
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` должен иметь только **два** непосредственных ребёнка - **левое меню** и **контейнер** для контента основного. У вас же в `DrawerLayout` целых **4** потомка. Оставьте только 2: контейнер + `NavigationView`

Comment: Насколько я понял, если занести includ'ы в coordinatorlayout проблема должна решиться?

Comment: @zTrap, скажем так: вероятность того, что проблема именно в этом - ненулевая.

Comment: увы, предложенный мной метод, не сработал. Есть ещё какие нибудь варианты, догадки, да что угодно?

Comment: @zTrap, Ну а если хедер убрать из дровера? И в логах больше никкой инфы об ошибке нет?..

Comment: Нет, @ЮрийСПб, это тоже не помогло

Comment: добавил весь лог с ошибкой

Comment: @zTrap, т.е. вы убрали хэдер, оставили только два потомка в DrawerLayout и всё одно падает и никакой инфы в логи не выдаёт?..

Comment: Убрал хедер - падает, убрал инклуды - падает, да и ошибка та же @ЮрийСПб

Comment: Согласно ошибке у вас какая-то иконка не найдена в меню, кое в NavigationView должно быть. Попробуйте иконки убрать и/или проверить их валидность и наличие.

Comment: Я готов на Вас молиться. Действительно, я не скопировал 1 иконку в drawable. Спасибо.

Comment: @zTrap, пожалуйста)